# Objective C ASIHTTPRequest nested GCD block in complete block

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting, asihttprequest, objective-c-blocks, grand-central-dispatch

I was wondering if this is the correct way to have nested blocks working on the same variable in Objective C without causing any memory problems or crashes with ARC. It starts with a ASIHttpRequest complete block.

```
MyObject *object = [dataSet objectAtIndex:i];

ASIHTTPRequest *request = [[ASIHTTPRequest alloc]initWithURL:@"FOO"];

__block MyObject *mutableObject = object;

[request setCompleteBlock:^{

      mutableObject.data = request.responseData;

      __block MyObject *gcdMutableObject = mutableObject;

      dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT,0),^{

              [gcdMutableObject doLongComputation];

              dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),^{

                     [self updateGUIWithObject:gcdMutableObject];
              }); 

      });

[request startAsynchronous];
```

My main concern is nesting the dispatch queues and using the __block version of the previous queue to access data. Is what I am doing safe?

Comment: Why do you have so many pointers to the same object?  Also, it is not a matter of "safety" but what you **want** to happen.  If you specify your desired intent, that would help provide more appropriate responses.  Otherwise, I am tempted to just look at that code, shake my head, and move on.

Comment: My intent is that object is modified in each block level and safely returned to the main thread in the innermost block.

Comment: You are abusing __block. Just use it once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// Under ARC the blocks will automatically retain <object>
MyObject *object = [dataSet objectAtIndex:i];
ASIHTTPRequest *request = [[ASIHTTPRequest alloc]initWithURL:@"FOO"];
__weak ASIHTTPRequest *weakRequest = request;                        // EDIT
[request setCompleteBlock:^{
    // <object> is retained by the block.
    // Changing a property of <object> but not <object> itself.
    ASIHTTPRequest *request = weakRequest;                           // EDIT
    if (!request) return;                                            // EDIT
    object.data = request.responseData;    
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT,0),^{
        // <object> retained by this block too...
        [object doLongComputation];
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),^{
            // <object> retained by this block too
            // Note, <self> is also retained...
            // Use the same "weak" trick if you don't want this      // EDIT
            [self updateGUIWithObject:object];
        });
    });
}];
[request startAsynchronous];
```

**EDIT**

`endy` does bring up a valid point (though using `__usnafe_unretained` should be generally avoided.  While I did originally note that both request and self are retained in the original post, I assumed appropriate measures would be taken as necessary.  That was not a wrong decision on my part.

So, there are several ways to break the retain cycle for this request, but using a weak reference is probably the safest and best choice here.

See the lines marked with `// EDIT` in the above code.

Comment: Thanks this is exactly what I was looking for. Wasn't sure if modifying a property required the __block tag

Comment: This will cause a Retain cycle. http://www.imagesnatcher.com/img/8c8cf03df804b7f3/f5a836.png

Comment: As noted in the comment of the code... as an explanation of what is happening.  there are lots of ways to deal with retain cycles, the worst of which is using `__unsafe_unretained`.

Comment: @endy - You are right.  Even though I noted the retain specifically in the comments, I should have indicated how to avoid it.  Thanks.

Comment: Now you're just writing 3x the code in an attempt to avoid the request from being released after allocation. I promis you, __unsafe_unretained along with the static requestWithURL works perfectly fine. There is nothing wrong with using __unsafe_unretained if you use it right.

Comment: I agree -- there is nothing wrong with it when it's used right.  But, it's very easy to use wrong.  As a general way to avoid retain cycles, it can easily cause crashes, and its use is discouraged by Apple... and by me.  However, just as any tool, you are free to use whatever you want.  Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

I got a little lost with all the pointers to the same object but I think this is what you are looking for.

```
__block MyObject *object = [dataSet objectAtIndex:i];

__unsafe_unretained ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"FOO"]];


[request setCompleteBlock:^{

      object.data = request.responseData;


      dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT,0),^{

              [object doLongComputation];

              dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),^{

                     [self updateGUIWithObject:object];
              }); 

      });
}];
[request startAsynchronous];
```

Comment: `__unsafe_unretained ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"FOO"]];`  Herein lies danger.

Comment: No. herein lies no retain cycles. Don't be distracted by the unsafe in the name.

Comment: If you want to avoid the retain cycle, the last resort is `__unsafe_unretained`.  Using `__weak` is much more appropriate in almost every situation, including this one.